# Unable to add Menu Items due to IntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: database, navigation

## Background

I recently encountered an error when I try to create a new menu item:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => menu_link_content:83480782-adf3-4c99-82fa-e91ba2885eb5 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => main ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 817 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

Other parts of the site appear to be working fine from what I can see, but I simply can not create any new menu links.

## Unknown Cause

I do not know what is the cause of this issue, but it occurred shortly after I changed the collation of the tables and columns to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. I had setup the database to use `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` when I created it, but for some reason this only set the database collation, so new tables and columns were using `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. This resulted in the MySQL dumps causing errors when I tried to import them into the staging database.

I had to run some SQL queries to find which tables and columns were wrong, and to set the correct charset and collation. This fixed the previous error and I could import the MySQL dump.

The reason I think this may be related is because when I looked up solutions for that issue, one of the solutions recommended disabling foreign keys for the table alter statements, and re-enabling them after:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- Insert your other SQL Queries here...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

In the next section, some of the errors outputted by the Drush Watchdog come from `Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException` so I am wondering if my earlier fix may have instead broken something in the database.

The other major change since I last tried to create a menu item is that I updated Drupal `10.1.4` to `10.1.6`.

## Drush Watchdog Output

I found a few issues discussing this on the Drupal forum. Most of these are VERY old, around 7-10 year. The fixes were not recommended as per the comments, however this command I found on one of the issues provides a log of some of these error messages:

```
drush watchdog-show
 ------ -------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  ID     Date           Type                Severity   Message                                                                                                                                                                                       
 ------ -------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  1593   17/Nov 10:45   php                 Error      Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VALUES (:db_insert_  
  1592   17/Nov 10:45   menu_link_content   Error      Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VA  
  1591   17/Nov 10:41   php                 Error      Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VALUES (:db_insert_  
  1590   17/Nov 10:41   menu_link_content   Error      Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VA  
  1589   17/Nov 10:40   menu                Error      Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VA  
  1588   17/Nov 10:40   views               Info       The view Statistics has been deleted.                                                                                                                                                         
  1587   16/Nov 16:53   php                 Error      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 67 of /Users  
  1586   16/Nov 16:53   menu                Error      Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VA  
  1585   16/Nov 16:40   menu                Error      Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VA  
  1584   16/Nov 16:40   system              Info       charts_billboard module installed.                                                                                                                                                            
 ------ -------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Drush updb Output

I found another [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3244053) where numerous users had a similar issue and resolved it with `drush updb`. I ran this and got the same error output.

```
drush updb 
 [success] No pending updates.
 [error]  Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO "menu_tree" ("id", "menu_name") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => charts.settings
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => tools
)
 in Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\ExceptionHandler->handleExecutionException() (line 43 of /Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/cab/web/core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/ExceptionHandler.php).
```